# Which paypal method should be used for direct / indirect payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am working on one website which has 2 mode of payment for already generated invoice by website.

**Method 1.** User log in to site, click on invoice and Pay. For this method i have to follow which method where user come back to site with additional parameter i have sent?

**Method 2.** If user has provided his credit card details, then with help of cronjob / schedule task, payment should be processed and it should notify to website (IPN). For this method i have to follow which method? This is not recurring payment.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the DoDirectPayment API for both.  This would allow you to process a charge at the time the buyer is checking out, or later through your cron job.  Keep in mind that the DoDirectPayment API will only let the buyer pay with a credit card though.  If you are wanting the buyer to be able to pay with their PayPal account as well, then you would need to also use Express Checkout.

Comment: Thanx @PP_MTS_Chad for your response. UK based account support DoDirectPayment as credit card processing OR it is only available in US account? For sandbox it will workout but for live it will work? I also found integration link of DoDirectPayment at [link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-process-credit-cards-with-paypal-payments-pro-using-php/). Can i process with this?

Comment: Correct, you can use direct credit card processing on UK accounts.